# pythonでファイルを読み込みしようとするとエラーが出ます。

Tags: python

pythonでファイルを読み込みしようとすると、

```
file_object = open('C:\Users\　　　\Documents\　　　.png','r')
```

以下のエラーが出ます。

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: \Uがエスケープ文字として処理されていると思います。上記リンクご覧ください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。出来ました。